# Visual Studio Mac, Android release signed is older than current build

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I'm using `Visual Studio mac` for developing `Xamarin`, recently I released my `Android` app but a rare behave happened! Releasing app popped out 2 files named `app.apk` and `app-Signed.apk` and I think the 2nd one should be the one I should upload to `Google Play store` (am I right?), but after opening it on my device I found out many changes that was appearing in debug app are not exist in `Singned` one! while `app.apk` is OK with changes I applied to app.

1. Is `app.apk` in debug mode?
2. What should be `app-Signed.apk` and why it has this problem and how can I fix it (if answer to #1 is true)?

Comment: Did you perform an Archive / Sign - Distribute to create the XXX.apk, or just perform a build on a Release configuration?

Comment: Of curse I performed archive for publishing process

Comment: Then you should not have an apk with `Signed` in the name, you should end up with one apk (or more if you are splitting ABIs) in the output folder named with your bundle id (and ABI if splitting), i.e. `com.sushihangover.MovieMadness-arm64-v8a.apk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes Visual Studio Mac for some reason does that. Remove obj and bin folder from a project directory, and then build again. If that happens again (2 files) the odd thing that you need to upload to google play non signed one.